# mapping a property to a column of a different table in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mapping

i have a fixed set of classes in my domain model, and the oracle database model is also fixed. The target is now to create appropriate mapping files. Please advise.

public class ElementC extends AuditableEntityC implements Element{

```
private String name;
private String type;
private String model;
private String vendor;
private String hostName;
private String ipAddr;

private Properties properties;
```

The corresponding tables in database:

CREATE TABLE "TYPE" ( "TYPE_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL , "NAME" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR) NOT NULL , "DESCR" VARCHAR2(500 CHAR), CONSTRAINT "ELEMENT_TYPE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("TYPE_ID") ) ;

and

CREATE TABLE "ELEMENT" ( "ELEMENT_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL , "TYPE" INTEGER NOT NULL , "NAME" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR) NOT NULL , "STATUS" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), "VENDOR" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR), "HOSTURL" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR), "LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP , CONSTRAINT "ELEMENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ELEMENT_ID")

) ;

in the database, the type column in element table is a foreign key to TYPE table.

note that the type attribute in my ElementC.java is a string, so how do i map it to the name column of the TYPE table. i cannot change the table structure nor the java file.